# How does Discord or Telegram send Push Notifications to channels on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, server, push-notification

So, I'm working on a chat app and I am having trouble sending notifications using FCM to chat groups or channels.

There are 2 options I tried using:
**Device groups**: This is perfect but, The docs says that I can only add 20 devices to a group and that's no good as I need many more to be added.

**Topic Messaging**: This is also good but I wish there was a way to restrict hackers from joining to other topics and getting notifications from private messages/channels.

A third option is to store everyones device token in my database and then send each one a notification but this sounds so inefficient but I'm not really sure. Is this approach fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the 3rd option.
I don't know if Firebase supports such option yet.

- At user's login save their FCM token
- Group user's in your database
- Run a foreach loop to send push notifications to the users that belong in one group.

I'm doing this in my own application and there is no much delay in Push notification delivery.

If you are using PHP as your server language you can use the [curl_multi_init](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)
This will send all the request at the same time. Hence the time required for your server to send all the Push notifications will be around 300ms.

On the other hand if you are not using PHP, there must be some similar ways you can achieve the same in your preferred language.

Keep in mind that there is no best implementation. It depends on the number of users using your app. It wouldn't be that wise to over-engineer this when you can do it really simple.

Comment: would using a firebase cloud messaging topic do the job